# Use params in http url Angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Assume that: `http://localhost:7030/profile/5732fe4c56575e05089469dd`

How can i get the information from this **id** `5732fe4c56575e05089469dd` in $http url ?

here's the code :

Nodejs :

```
router.get(':id/api/data.json', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
    var userId = req.params.id;
    User.findById({_id:userId}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err
        if (doc){
            res.json({
                doc: doc,
                userID:userId
                });
        }
    });
});
```

**Angular**

```
$http.get("/profile/api/data.json").then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

something like this : $http.get("url + id + data.json");

How can i access this id from server to angular

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nodejs

```
router.get('/profile/:id/data.json', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.params.id);
        var userId = req.params.id;
        User.findById({_id:userId}, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) throw err
            if (doc){
                res.json({
                    doc: doc,
                    userID:userId
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

Angular JS

```
$http.get("http://localhost:7030/profile/" +id + "/data.json").then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
```

Comment: I got : Error id is not a function

Comment: id should have been instatiated before the http is being called. like so
var id = "5732fe4c56575e05089469dd";

Comment: You have to be getting your UserID from somewhere.. where do you get the userID from

Comment: i've passed it from node : res.json({
                    doc: doc,
                    userID:userId
                    });

Comment: You don't pass it like that. You are making a request from your angular code. Not the other way around.. Its the front-end that determines what comes in from the backend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113464/discussion-between-sani-and-abiodun).

Comment: can you tell me how can i pass it ?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: i'm here again , let's chat buddy @Abiodun